# Merge lists of lists beginning at certain element in first list

Tags: python

Beginning at A[2], I want to merge B[0] into A[2] and so on for both lists.  List A has more elements than B so I want to do this for all of the elements in B.

```
A = [[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3], [4,4,4], [5,5,5], [6,6,6], [7,7,7], ...]
B = [[6,6,6], [7,7,7], [8,8,8]]
```

Desired output

```
merged_list = [[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3,6,6,6], [4,4,4,7,7,7], [5,5,5,8,8,8], [6,6,6], [7,7,7] ....]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add empty lists in front of `B`, as needed, to align the two lists. `zip` the lists and concatenate them pairwise:

```
offset = 2 # Align at position #2
[x+y for x,y in zip(A, [[]] * offset + B)]
#[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6], ...]
```

Comment: Although the merging works, I noticed a problem.  List A is much longer than list B. The formula stops merging the lists after B runs out of items.  I need the rest of list A to be merged also.  I will alter the example to illustrate.

Comment: Just append more empty lists to B at the end, as needed.